# An equivalent condition to local compactness

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

I was writing a Haskell API for topological properties. One property that was hard to exploit was local compactness (where I take Hausdorff-ness as a prerequisite), so I sought for an equivalent condition for it. One particular such condition I found was:

> A Hausdorff space $X$ is locally compact  if and only if $X$ admits a basis whose every basis element has compact closure.

Proof (forward):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for $X$. Let $\mathcal{B}' = \{B \in \mathcal{B} : \overline{B} \text{ is compact}\}$. I show that $\mathcal{B}'$ is still a basis.

(Coverage) Let $x \in X$. Pick $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$. Since $X$ is locally compact, there is a compact set $C \subset B$ containing a neighborhood $U$ of $x$.  Pick $B' \in \mathcal{B}$  such that $x \in B' \subset U$. Then since $\overline{B'} \subset \overline{C} = C$, $\overline{B'}$ is compact, and thus $B' \in \mathcal{B}'$.

(Intersection) Let $B, B' \in \mathcal{B}'$ whose intersection is nonempty. For every $x \in B \cap B'$, pick $B'' \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B'' \subset B \cap B'$. Then $\overline{B''} \subset \overline{B \cap B'} \subset \overline{B} \cap \overline{B'} \subset \overline{B}$. Since $\overline{B}$ is compact, so is $\overline{B''}$. Thus $B'' \in \mathcal{B}'$.

The last step is to show that $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ generate the same topology. Since $\mathcal{B}' \subset \mathcal{B}$, the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}'$ is coarser than that of $\mathcal{B}$. To show that it is also finer, for every $B \in \mathcal{B}$, pick $B' \in \mathcal{B}'$ as in the (Coverage) proof above. Then $B' \subset B$. ∎

Proof (converse):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ a basis for $X$ whose every basis element has compact closure. For every $x \in X$, pick a basic neighborhood $B \in \mathcal{B}$ of $x$. Then $\overline{B}$ is a compact set containing a neighborhood of $x$, namely $B$. ∎

Note that this construction preserves second-countability.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: The proof looks good. Just a small remark, the fact that second countability is preserved is obvious, since you showed that the two topologies are the same *any* topological property is preserved